# QTestLib - Verifying non-const reference arguments

Tags: unit-testing, qt, reference, qtestlib

I'm currently building a unit test suite for my application, using `QTestLib`.  It's generally pretty straight-forward, but I'm become stuck on how to verify 'return' arguments.  For example, if I have a function:

```
double pointLineSegmentDistance(const QVector2D& start,
                                const QVector2D& end,
                                const QVector2D& point,
                                bool& withinBounds);
```

The function assigns `withinBounds` the bounded state of the segment distance analysis.  How can I make the `QCOMPARE`/`QVERIFY` macros analyse it's state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a local variable as argument and verify/compare its value afterwards:

```
bool withinBounds = false;
const double distance = pointLineSegmentDistance( ..., withinBounds );
QCOMPARE(distance + 1.0, 2.0); //qFuzzyCompare doesn't work well with 0.0
QVERIFY(withinBounds);
```

Comment: The [QCOMPARE](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtest.html#QCOMPARE) line should actually be: QCOMPARE(distance + 1.0, expected + 1.0) to handle zero values.